# swift predicate results in an error unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x156c9580'

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, predicate, nsfetchrequest

The following code is fetching data from core data. I am using the time stamp to get the correct results, the entity run has a relationship with location (this is a running app) the Full code shows you how i it all looks like. However when i try to fetch the data everything works good but when i use predicate to father only the data from a certain date and time **i am getting the error**

> unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x156c9580'

I am using the following code to fetch the data

```
func workoutFetch(){
        var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Run")
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "timestamp = %@", "2015-10-13 21:10:31")
        workoutDetails = managedObjectContext?.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as! [Run]

        for workout in workoutDetails {
            println(workout.timestamp)
        }
    }
```

For some reason the code is working when i am not using predicate and i can print out all the time stamps. So the fetching is working. I am certainly not a pro and i am really not good with core data so i would like to know why this is not working and how you should shear the database properly.

The full code which can give you a little insight to what i am trying to do.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import HealthKit
import CoreData

class DetailViewController: UIViewController{

    var run: Run!

    var workoutDate:String!

    var workoutDetails = [Run]()

    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext?

  @IBOutlet weak var snapshotImage: UIImageView!
  @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
  @IBOutlet weak var distanceLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var paceLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    @IBAction func saveWorkout(sender: AnyObject) {
    }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    activityIndicator.hidden = true

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)

    if (run != nil){

        configureView()

    }else{

    workoutFetch()

    }

  }

    func workoutFetch(){
        var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Run")
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "timestamp = %@", "2015-10-13 21:10:31")
        workoutDetails = managedObjectContext?.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as! [Run]

        for workout in workoutDetails {
            println(workout.timestamp)
        }
    }


    @IBAction func slideOutMenu(sender: AnyObject) {
        var appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        appDelegate.centerContainer!.toggleDrawerSide(MMDrawerSide.Left,  animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func musicTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        var appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.centerContainer!.toggleDrawerSide(MMDrawerSide.Right,  animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


  func configureView() {
    let distanceQuantity = HKQuantity(unit: HKUnit.meterUnit(), doubleValue: run.distance.doubleValue)
    distanceLabel.text = "Afstand: " + distanceQuantity.description

    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
    dateLabel.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(run.timestamp)

    let secondsQuantity = HKQuantity(unit: HKUnit.secondUnit(), doubleValue: run.duration.doubleValue)
    timeLabel.text = "Tijd: " + secondsQuantity.description

    let paceUnit = HKUnit.secondUnit().unitDividedByUnit(HKUnit.meterUnit())
    let paceQuantity = HKQuantity(unit: paceUnit, doubleValue: run.duration.doubleValue / run.distance.doubleValue)
    paceLabel.text = "Snelheid: " + paceQuantity.description

    loadMap()
  }

  func mapRegion() -> MKCoordinateRegion {
    let initialLoc = run.locations.firstObject as! Location

    var minLat = initialLoc.latitude.doubleValue
    var minLng = initialLoc.longitude.doubleValue
    var maxLat = minLat
    var maxLng = minLng

    let locations = run.locations.array as! [Location]

    for location in locations {
      minLat = min(minLat, location.latitude.doubleValue)
      minLng = min(minLng, location.longitude.doubleValue)
      maxLat = max(maxLat, location.latitude.doubleValue)
      maxLng = max(maxLng, location.longitude.doubleValue)
    }

    return MKCoordinateRegion(
      center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (minLat + maxLat)/2,
        longitude: (minLng + maxLng)/2),
      span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: (maxLat - minLat)*1.1,
        longitudeDelta: (maxLng - minLng)*1.1))
  }

  func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay!) -> MKOverlayRenderer! {
    if !overlay.isKindOfClass(MulticolorPolylineSegment) {
      return nil
    }

    let polyline = overlay as! MulticolorPolylineSegment
    let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: polyline)
    renderer.strokeColor = polyline.color
    renderer.lineWidth = 4
    return renderer
  }

  func polyline() -> MKPolyline {
    var coords = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()

    let locations = run.locations.array as! [Location]
    for location in locations {
      coords.append(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.latitude.doubleValue,
        longitude: location.longitude.doubleValue))
    }

    return MKPolyline(coordinates: &coords, count: run.locations.count)
  }

  func loadMap() {
    if run.locations.count > 0 {
      mapView.hidden = false

    } else {
      // No locations were found!
      mapView.hidden = true

      UIAlertView(title: "Error",
        message: "Sorry, this run has no locations saved",
        delegate:nil,
        cancelButtonTitle: "OK").show()
    }
  }



}// end of uiviewcontroller class

// MARK: - MKMapViewDelegate
extension DetailViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
}
```

I really need some help to fix this, i have been on it for several days now without getting any closer to a solution or understanding what i am doing wrong.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

your predicate: `"timestamp = %@", "2015-10-13 21:10:31"` is trying to compare `timestamp` which is an `NSDate` with `"2015-10-13 21:10:31"` which is an `NSString`.

You need to replace the string with a date, generally this would be an `NSDate` that you calculated using `NSDateComponents` or receive from somewhere else (i.e. ideally not a date you've created by converting a string).

Comment: I noticed that i am using a string and not a nsdate just after i posted the question. However, i am getting the nsdate with nsfechtedcontroller in a different view controller, then i fill an array with all the dates and then use didselectrow to get the correct date and pass it to the next viewcontroller. The problem is that i can't append the array with nsdate, seems nsdate can't use append. So i had to use int then pass it on. Now i need to see a way to turn the string into a NSDate. How do i do that? or how do i add NSDate to an array.

Comment: I have solved the NSDate issue and it is giving me no errors however it is not not putting out anything it seems, only when i am not using predicate i am getting everything.

Comment: Presumably you don't actually want = in the predicate, you want < or >

Comment: But I am looking for an exact date, what should I be using then (==) or something else?

Comment: = is fine, but it must be exact to the millisecond to match, so a string conversion likely won't work

Comment: I am using a string because the nasal from another view controller has to passed on from a table view. I get all de dates from a array I fill with the data I fetch which I form put through a data formatter. I had to do that because I have no idea how to fill an array with Madame objects, so converted them to string and then back to a Madame object. The dates are same when you look at them

Comment: Typos are hilarious :-) convert to string only for display, keep the dates in the array and pass the date just like you do the string.

Comment: i would like to do that, but you can't append a nsdate to an array, what else than using append to add nsdates to an array

Comment: you can add any object to an array if you type it appropriately